# Understanding AWS Security Groups with Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-security-group

Ok, newbie here. Learning AWS. I have successfully deployed Spring Boot app via Fargate.

Before creating Task Definition I created a Security Groupe, and defined simple inbound rule like so:

[image]

After that, in task definition, under *Networking*:

[image]

If I try to hit: http://publicIp:8085/api/from/app - this doesn't work, but
http://publicIp:8080/api/from/app it does work.

I don't understand port mappings between these three things: SecurityGroupe - EC2 (reserved as part of Fargate launch type) - container in EC2?

Comment: If going to port `8080` works, then the software running in the container is listening on port `8080`. Since you haven't opened any ports in the security group other than `8080`, no other port is going to accept any traffic. Port mapping in the task definition needs to match the port that the software inside the container is actually listening on. But I think in this case the port mapping may not actually be used until you add a load balancer, which is why your port mapping setting didn't break anything.

Comment: Hm, my networking knowledge is horrible.. `Port mapping in the task definition needs to match the port that the software inside the container is actually listening on.` - Spring boot defaults to 8080, I haven't changed that, also in my Dockerfile, I haven't use `EXPOSE` command.  Okay, so you're saying that with current port mappings `http://publicIp:8085/api/from/app` will not pass once I add load balancer?

Comment: I'm saying you can't just randomly assign a port mapping like `8085`. It has to be the port that the software inside the container is actually listening on. The purpose of the port mapping is to tell the load balancer what port to send traffic to. It's a bit confusing because you have to configure that port in multiple places, so it seems redundant. I think the port mapping may be more important in EC2 deployments, where on Fargate it may not matter.

Comment: `http://publicIp:8085/api/from/app` is going directly to the container, it would bypass any load balancer, and since it's going to the wrong port it's never going to work. You also haven't opened that port in the security group, so again it is never going to work. Once you have a load balancer the URL would be `https://load-balancer-dns-name/api/from/app` and then the load balancer would forward traffic to your container.

Comment: Note sure that I understand all of this... I mean, with Docker you do `-p hostPortOfYourChoosing:portOfAppInsideContainer` (or specify port ranges) and you map them in that way. In example from AWS, security group somehow override this mapping like mapping is not even there or necessary. Haven't tried to mix in with loadbalancers yet. In any case, thank you for your comments, you can place an answer and I will accept it.